# Convert a Large JSON file into multiple JSON files with maximum 1000 lines

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to parse a large JSON file with ever increasing data into smaller files with a maximum of 1000 lines using Python.

So far I've managed to print upto a thousand lines, but now I'm stuck where to go next:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
count = 0
data = (lines for lines in f if count < 1000)
for x in data:
    count +=1
    print (x + str(count))
```

Since this needs to be a scalable solution, any other ideas on how I could do this better ?

EDIT:
 The inner structure of the JSON is similar to the following:
{"newsletter_optin": 1, "language": "gv", "country": "UY", "username": "xy32", "email": "xyz@gm.com", "user_id": 138123918}

I am working on a project where my mentor wants me to split a Large file with millions of JSON lines into mini files of 1000 lines each.

Comment: Could you give us more information about the inner structure of your JSON file?

Comment: Is this file too big to enter in memory? Is a file which contains a list of JSON valid documents o it is just one document?

Comment: Is this a good idea? You're segmenting valid JSON into separate files. How will you recombine it later?

Comment: If your data is lots of seperate values in a JSON list, you may want to consider using http://jsonlines.org/ instead of straight JSON

Comment: Your generator here, that relies on global state, is pretty brittle. It always goes through the entire file. You want `from itertools import islice; islice(f, 1000)`. But that is only if you *wanted* to do this, which isn't clear, since you can't just arbitrarily break apart a JSON file and expect the results to be meaningful..

Answer (score 0):

JSON files have an inner structure, so you can't just break it on any line, because the result would not be a valid JSON. Since JSON files are a combination of dictionaries and list nested within one another it makes the most sense to break the JSON separating elements of the same list.

here is an example:

```
{'Big JSON':[{'little JSON1':values},{'little JSON2':values}]}
```

This could be broken up to

```
{'Big JSON':[{'little JSON1':values}]}
```

and

```
{'Big JSON':[{'little JSON2':values}]}
```

The exact code for breaking the JSON up depends on the inner structure of your JSON file. But it is important that each of your files be a stand alone valid JSON file